# Concatenate two values or variables in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I am new with angularJS. and trying to concatenate two variables?

```
ng-init = "imgid={{$parent.$index+$index}}"
```

also tried=>

```
setImgCounter(post.postImages.length,$parent.$index+$index)
```

here `$index=3 and $oarent.$index=3`. I want something like 33 but it is showing me 6 . `setImgCounter` is a function and I want to send `$parent.$index+$index` as a variable.is there any way to achieve 33 instate of 6.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert your integers to string to concatenate, then the resulting string back to integer for later process (I imagine):

```
parseInt($parent.$index+""+$index)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing something like

```
ng-init = "imgid={{$parent.$index}}{{$index}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
ng-init = "imgid={{$parent.$index+' '+$index}}"
```